# how to connect sql server 2008 with eclipse helios using data source explorer

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to connect Sql Server 2008 database with Eclipse using database source explorer,
could you help me ?

- in Eclipse->
- Windows ->
- open Perspective ->
- others ->
- Database Development ->
- OK

I got DataSource Explores Screen, then

- in database Connection->
- rightClick ->
- click new ->
- connection` profile will open.

In that i have selected

- sqlserver->
- next ->
- driver details ->
- i have selected sqljdbc4.jar file because iam using jdk1.6

In next tab we can see properties like connection url and driver class my doute is my system is client system i want to connect with server my server name is SQL1. But in URL there is no ServerName.

it can't establish connection

> Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seen this issue before. Copy sqljdbc_auth.dll to the working directory, should sort it.

Other than that SQL server isn't running, or it's a firewall issue. Or something else potentially is using that port.